# What kind of exceptions while deserializing triggers kafka streams default.deserialization.exception.handler?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka StreamConfig:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG , LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
...
```

For example i have custom deserializer implementation:

```
public class KeyDeserializer implements Deserializer<Key>
```

Is my assumption right - if any Runtime exception that will occur during deserialization in `deserialize` method will be cached by default deserialization exception handler or only some kind of Kafka specific ones?

```
@Override
public Key deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes)
```

I have not found any explanation in docs. I must be sure that whatever happens during deserialization stream going to log and continue streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. When Kafka Streams attempts to deserialize, any exception that occurs is handed over to the `DeserializationExceptionHandler`, so it's up to the handler how to handle it.

The default config uses the [LogAndFailExceptionHandler](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.2/org/apache/kafka/streams/errors/LogAndFailExceptionHandler.html), which does just what the name implies.  Kafka Streams also provides a [LogAndContinueExceptionHandler](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.2/org/apache/kafka/streams/errors/LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.html), or you could provide your own implementation.

Comment: I have a LogAndContinueExceptionHandler and I can see it kicking in when deserialization errors occur while reading from input topics.

However, when such errors occur while reading from persisted state stores, the topology is shutdown. Is there a way to handle this scenario gracefully and prevent a shutdown ?

Comment: You'll need a try-catch in those cases to handle the exception.  This will be easier if you use the Processor API and have direct access to the store.  Another option, if you're using the DSL, is to implement a serializer and deserializer with try-catch around the serialize and deserialize methods and handle the error.  Then, use the Serdes.from(serializer, deserializer) to create the Serde for the store.